# pdo error message pop-up error

Tags: php, pdo, dreamweaver

ok so im new to pdo and have made a simple login system but cannot get an error message to pop up when the user leaves their username or password blank but i am having no luck i got the code this far through research and help from others but i am stumped now. any help will be fantastic bear in mind that i am new to this.

P.S i know this is not a secure system

here is the code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //connection String
    $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=server;Database=database", "username", "password"); 

    //Seelcting function
    $smt = $connection->prepare("select user_id, username from account where username = :username and password =:password");

    //setting values to textboxes
    $username = $_POST["txt_username"];
    $password = $_POST["txt_password"];

    //binding values
    $smt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $smt->bindParam(':password', $password);

    //execution
    $smt->execute();

    //fetching data
    $row = $smt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ;  
    echo "$row[user_id]\n\n";
    echo "$row[username]\n\n";
    $_SESSION{"user_id"} = $row["user_id"];



if ($smt->recordCount() == 0){
  $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "login failed";
  header( "location: login.php");
} else{
  header("location: homepage.php");
}


if( isset( $_SESSION['errormsg'] ) ) {
  // do the output
  echo $_SESSION['errormsg'];
  // delete the message from the session, so that we show it only once
  unset( $_SESSION['errormsg'] );
}



?>
```

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834106/php-pdo-echo-alert-error

Comment: Please, do not ask the same question more than once.

Comment: Using different accounts, too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like you are unsetting your error right after you set it.  Change the order so it checks if error msg is set then redirects with error.